# Tool to save own color table with CMYK, GRB and HSL

Tags: color, colortable

Im looking for a tool to save my colors with CMYK, RGB and HSL. So that I can print and compare, write some notes to every color and easy extract.  Any idea?

Im mainly using Inkscape, Gimp and QGIS on xUbuntu. Its for maping purpose.

Comment: What software are you using ? What is the type of data ? Where is the original color stored ?

Comment: I added some details to the question...

Comment: Color Schemer http://www.workwithcolor.com/hsl-color-schemer-01.htm